# What was considered utility clothing before WW2?

Tags: fashion

The term *Utility Clothing* became associated with Britain's [Utility Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_clothing) during WW2.

However, apparently such a "utility" in fashion seems to have been known even before this time.

I came across an article entitled [Utility Futility](https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1110&context=phr), which expands upon the word *Utility* and its associated negative fashion meanings which were present ***before*** the commissioning of the 1941 scheme.

Here is a relevant excerpt from that article (bold is mine):

> Why was “Utility” such an inadequate label? First, **it had been used in the clothing industry before to describe a type of heavy-duty garment designed to weather tough use, the equivalent of what consumers today might think of as blue-collar “work clothes.” It appeared with relative frequency in advertisements for coats and jackets well before the Utility scheme’s conception,** proving that consumers already had a preexisting idea in mind when they heard the word “Utility,” an idea contrary to the reality of Utility scheme clothes<sup>35</sup> […] “Utility” made consumers picture drab, unflattering jumpsuits.

> The first verdict came in February 1942, when the *Drapers’ Record*, a prominent journal for clothiers and other sectors of the clothing industry, released one of the earliest articles surveying women’s initial receptions of the Utility scheme. The article began by pointing out that since Utility had yet to make a significant appearance in stores, many of the women interviewed based their opinions solely on their impressions of the word “Utility,” rather than on firsthand experience. **One interviewee commented that “Utility” made her think of a uniform – “government stuff, sackcloth.” Another interviewee worried Utility clothing would be “clumsy and heavy.” Still another expected colors to be “dark and uninteresting.”** The reporter even added that these three women had not heard about the scheme before being interviewed about it, further demonstrating the power of the word “Utility” to produce negative first impressions of the entire project.

Are there online first-hand resources regarding such clothings deemed to be like these 'utility clothings' later (e.g., pictures or illustrations of such "utility clothings" from that time)?

The article does refer to a Vogue advertisement of that time of interest:

> <sup>35</sup> Advertisement for Allama “Utility” coats. Vogue, February 1939, p. 29.

But there's no such an advertisement in both [February 1](https://archive.vogue.com/article/1939/02/01/admiration) and [February 15](https://archive.vogue.com/article/1939/02/15/advertisement-2) issues' page 29 (nor some other page, to the best I could see).

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace, your edit changed my question purpose: The title before edit specifically mentioned: **regardless** of the World Wars. I also specficially mention in the question: **before** the commissioning of the scheme. That Wiki article refers to what I'm not interested in.

Comment: Downvoters, please specify what's wrong with my question. Don't make me think it was because you actually didn't read my question carefully ;)

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace, thanks for the feedback! as for 2) I'll add my comment to you regarding the Wiki article to my question, I think it fairly clarifies why it's irrelevant, and for 3) The downvoting was done after you changed my title to be a question, so that wasn't the reason.

Comment: May I suggest to pre-empt the 'pictures' with an inquiry into the very *meaning* of 'utility clothing' before 1939? That word is just so ambiguous & searches now obscured by 'the scheme'. The refs you cite are about attributions ("made to think of…"). I guess, once that's cleared up, actual pictures of such things will come easy?

Comment: Vogue claims to have an entire archive online, like here https://archive.vogue.com/issue/19390201 registration required (& not working for me…) But I strongly repeat my hunch that this is formost a language and meaning issue, about 'clothing deemed to be with/of utility' more than anything else.

Comment: @LаngLаngС, that's a nice suggestion. I edited my question to address what I think you mean - did I get your intention right?

Comment: I read [google ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22utility+clothing%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%22%20utility%20clothing%20%22%3B%2Cc0) as support for @LangLangC's theory that this is a language/semiotics issue.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace, if you remove the double quotes from your linked search string, you'll get results - mostly from the 1940s, but also prior and after - which are actually double quoted. I know that sounds weird, so here are the [results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22utility%20clothing%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1941&lr=lang_en) until 1941.

Comment: If I may explain in comments: before 'scheme' "utility" in clothing was sen as akin to 'practical/working class' (thus connoting cheap, dull, etc) ie: anathema to (high) 'fashion' (impractical, but nice looking, 'en vogue', 'modern', rare , expensive, etc). As the excellent src-artcl by Durfee explains: "*seen* as"; a terrible misnomer for a pol campaign (whose results were rather sexy CC41-cuts, despite limits-frame, IncSOC designers being trained properly in trade & taste & style) — mismatch in comm between subjects & well-meaning civ-servants (cue MA&earlymod-style  sumptuāriae lēgēs).

Comment: Of course:  *deemed* "'impractical"' for certain applications. Like: high-heels vs wellingtons; oil-cloth vs silk-pelerines; for once. Am quite sure, As have to ref aspects of *that* angle, perhaps in general, but certainly for 1900–1940 (like "rare" vs 'the standard' after 1917).

Comment: This question might need a geographical tag. My ancestors prior to WWII were farmers, and their utility clothing was (literally) overalls.

Answer (score 4):

After some digging into this question, I realise that @LangLangC's comments are right.

Looking at the dictionary, one of the lexical meanings of the adjective [*utility*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/utility) is:

> **utility**
> […]
> **2**: Functional rather than attractive.

Correspondingly, the term *utility clothing* had (and actually still is, but I'm limiting myself here to pre-WW2) referred to functional clothes, serving primarily for utility rather than beauty.

While in some contexts *utility clothing* refer to everyday clothes, which may actually be stylish (though not "dressy"), in some other contexts this term just referred to work clothes, which of course are not supposed to be attractive.
It is understandable, then, why those women interviewed back in 1942 – in the lack of firsthand experience with Utility Scheme clothes – had the impression that such clothes will look bad.

Let's demonstrate with examples these two related meanings, i.e., *utility clothing* (1) as a juxtaposition to *dressy clothing*, and (2) as simply meaning work clothes.

*Note: unfortunately, all examples are from American sources, not British ones.*

**(1) *utility* as a juxtaposition to *dressy***

**The Mother's Magazine, Volume 12** ([source](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=50RJAAAAYAAJ&q=%22utility+coat%22&dq=%22utility+coat%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwimlfP9se3vAhV_gP0HHUsOBpI4FBDoATAJegQICBAC). published in New York, 1844):

[image]

**Textile-apparel Analysis - Volume 4** ([source](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22utility+coat%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1800,cd_max:12/31/1939&tbm=bks&ei=IlNuYJOHEcnh7_UPxv6Z-AI&start=100&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwiToJfgtu3vAhXJ8LsIHUZ_Bi84WhDw0wMInQE&biw=1344&bih=726&dpr=1.25). published in New York, 1928):

[image]

**Where and how to Sell Manuscripts** ([source](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=y6guAQAAIAAJ&q=%22utility+wear%22&dq=%22utility+wear%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiy_KfHvu7vAhWEgf0HHStJBoA4HhDoATAGegQIAhAC). published in Massachusetts, 1919):

[image]

Now take a look at this advertisement by Lane Bryant for maternity clothing, from 1917 ([source](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=7LI7AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA117&dq=%22utility+coat%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiD7KKJre3vAhUGhf0HHVLtDXUQ6AEwBnoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22utility%20coat%22&f=false), from Vogue, volume 49, number 4, February 1917) – this utility coat looks quite nice, isn't it?:

[image]

**(2) *utility clothes* are just *work clothes***

1. NOGAR's utility clothes, ad from 1927 ([source](https://web.archive.org/save/https://www.ebay.com/itm/1927-OLD-MAGAZINE-PRINT-AD-NOGAR-UTILITY-CLOTHES-MADE-TO-STAND-UP-FASHION-ART-/291024534406)):

[image]

2. Duxbak's utility clothes, ad from 1918 ([Popular Science Monthly, volume 93, November 1918](https://books.google.co.il/books?redir_esc=y&id=ICkDAAAAMBAJ&q=utility+clothes#v=onepage&q=%22utility%20clothes%22&f=true)):

[image]